# How can I get all the .pdb files in the same folder?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging, pdb-files

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2008, it has dozens of projects.

I would like to have all the pdb in the same folder.

From the property page of a project I see that the pdb will go to the "Intermediate Directory"; also .obj files go to the "Intermediate Directory".

Each of our projects has its own folder because we want to keep the .obj separated, at the same time I would like to have all the pdb in the same folder.

Looking at the buildlog.htm I see the option /PDB which controls the pdb path, this option doesn't seem to me available in the property page.

Maybe I will have to use a post buil script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm only using Visual Studio 2005, but here the PDB path is controlled via the **Linker** Property Tab -> **Debugging** -> create program data base.

The path here defaults to `$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).pdb` and that is the directory where your output (binary) goes to.
Are you sure, you didn't mix that with the **Compiler** -> **Output** options? the PDB Path you set there is only for the precompiled headers.

Comment: Thank you very much, Visual Studio 2008 is like 2005.